# Reverse engineered project to graphical UML diagram

Tags: c++, uml, reverse-engineering, diagram, graphic

I've started to work on a quite big C++ project. I've used `BOUML` to import the code base with the intention to create a visual UML diagram.
Now I've reversed the project and I see the classes, namespaces, methods and such in the project browser but I can't figure out how to create a graphical UMl from it, may anyone here help me?
Manually draggign the elements from the browser into the main area doesn't seem to be allowed as the cursor gets a forbidden icon and dropping the elments doesn't do anything then... how do I even create the UML myself?

Comment: If you can convert it to a codebase, you can visualize the class hierarchy in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: @seccpur I don't have Visual Studio, I'm on `Linux`, any tools available on this platform? I do have the codebase and am looking to create a graphical representation of it

Comment: Not that I’ve used BOUML, but it looks like you need to add diagrams under a view (e.g. add class diagram under a class view) based on their doco. Stick with it — definitely looks possible!

Answer (score 1):

muszeo2 is right, the reverse create the packages / views / artifacts and classes and their members, after you have to create the diagrams by yourself. Sorry but BoUML is not extra lucid and it cannot by itself create the right diagrams of the right kind containing the right elements with the right drawing options ;-) So create your diagrams and drag&drop the elements you want to show etc, they are several features helping you to make diagrams with elements already created or not.

Comment: Hi Bruno, please see the original question, I've added further details, following your comment above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also made some video tutorials available on https://www.bouml.fr/documentation.html, I encourage you to look at them, starting by starting.wmv then cpp_example.wmv for instance, but you can also look at the others because the rules are quite identicals. These video tutorials are old and many features was added since I made them, but this is a good start.

You cannot drag&drop from browser to no where (I mean not into an opened diagram) nor when the element cannot be added in a diagram

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to post two similar but different answers. Better to delete this one and edit the previous answer.